# ReferenceError after loading a script using $.getScript()

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have JS file hosted at https://cdn.rawgit.com/DarkPotatoKing/darkpotatoking.github.io/master/latest_version.js

When I run the following script on the browser console

```js
jQuery.getScript("https://cdn.rawgit.com/DarkPotatoKing/darkpotatoking.github.io/master/latest_version.js")
 .done(function() {
  alert("done");
 })
 .fail(function() {
  alert("fail");
});
```

I get a popup that says "done", but when I run

```
version.number()
```

the following error message is returned

```
ReferenceError: version is not define
```

Why is "version" not defined if the script is supposedly loaded properly?

Comment: from latest_version.js: SyntaxError: missing } after property list

Comment: I see, got it, it works now when I changed the script

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your script at has a syntax error, so it cannot be parsed. Correct your script, and version.number() will come:

```
var version = {
    number: function() { return "1.1"; }; <==Syntax error here
}
```

Of course you must call `version.number()` from inside `.done(function () {...})`

Answer (score 0):

## EDIT

Ok i solved it for you, you need to change that uploaded file to this:

```
var version = {
    number: function() { return "1.1"; }
}
```

you have a `;` to much in that code.

And this is your new javscript/jquery code:

```
$.getScript( "https://cdn.rawgit.com/DarkPotatoKing/darkpotatoking.github.io/master/latest_version.js" )
.done(function( script, textStatus ) {
    console.log(version.number);
})
.fail(function( jqxhr, settings, exception ) {
    console.log("nope");
});
```

---

## OLD

This is because your code is not in sync.

if you run `version.number()` inside the .done it must work.

Comment: I replaced 'alert("done")' with 'vs = version.number()', but when I access vs after that it says vs is undefined. What can I do to access the string returned by version.number() outside the getScript() call?

Comment: @DarkPotatoKing you need to stay inside the .done. Why? Little explanation: you request a file, that needs to download so javascript does not wait for that shit and runs the other code and when the file that was requested is downloaded. It wil run the .done code. So when you are outside the .done and ask for `vs = version.number()` it will say its undefined because the file is not loaded yet.